# In vim, how do I get a file to open at the same line number I closed it at last time?

Tags: vim

I want to configure vim to open a file at the same place I left off at.

Comment: :'"  apostrophe followed by double quotes redirects you last changes line

Answer (score 242):

From Ubuntu's `/etc/vim/vimrc` file, this example is commented out:

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
    \| exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

If this doesn't work, a common problem is not having ownership of your `~/.viminfo` file. If this is the case, then run:

```
sudo chown user:group ~/.viminfo
```

where user is your `username` and `group` is often the same as your username.

Comment: The autocmd comes straight out of the vim doc. See :help last-position-jump

Comment: If the single quote in the penultimate line is changed to a backtick, it will jump to the actual cursor position, not just the beginning of that line: `\| exe "normal! g\`\"" | endif`

Comment: The `chown` part fixed the problem for me. Hats off!

Comment: Had the setting but the permissions note made it work. Thanks.

Comment: Finally someone points out that my .viminfo is owned by root for some reason!  This needs to be in the other 100 documentations that I read.

Comment: Just want to +1 the `chown user ~/.viminfo` addition. I've been trying to figure this out for an hour now and you just saved my day.

Comment: the `chown` solution didn't work for me, so I just uncommented the lines in `/etc/vim/vimrc`

Comment: Great answer!  :-)  Note however the peculiarity that that this approach does not work on files opened using marks (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks).  If you go to a file "bookmarked" with a mark
(e.g., mW), then you will not automatically return to the previous cursor/line position, if that file is opened using the shortcut `W.

Comment: If you don't want edit `/etc/vim/vimrc` or `/etc/vimrc` (in my case, Arch Linux) you can also add this to your `~/.vimrc` and will work in the same way (I mean, I prefer do that config in the user side, not system-wide).

Comment: if anyone does the same mistake I made: remove `let skip_defaults_vim=1` and 
`set viminfo="` from `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Hey @jfernandz, you're comment solved my issue! I was editing `~/.viminfo` but it wasn't working. After adding the lines into `~/.vimrc`, it finally solved the issue! Many thanks!

Answer (score 66):

If you don't mind trading automation for simplicity, just press the keystroke <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> (apostrophe, followed by double quotes) on opening a file, you'll jump to where you were. This is essentially what @marcog's answer is doing.

Answer (score 30):

You can start vim without specifying a file name using

```
vim
```

Next press CTRL+O twice to move to the last location in any file you worked on.

Comment: If you have NERDTree installed, pressing C-o twice can open NERDTree in current buffer. In my case, I sometimes need to press C-o up to five times, but eventually I get the effect described by @MatAff.

Comment: Pressing `Ctrl-c` once is enough for me. In addition, pressing `Ctrl-c` more takes me further back in the cursor position histroy (even opening relevant unopened files). I use Neovim 0.4.2, but my understanding is that it applies to `vim` as well.

Answer (score 29):

`:h views-sessions`

You can place this in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```

the views will be placed in .vim/view. You probably need to create these directories.

Comment: I like this answer because the other one referred to an /etc/vim/ file that did not exist on my Mac.

Comment: I like this answer because it also restores the scroll position unlike the accepted answer

Comment: I needed to use `autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent! loadview` or else every new file I opened showed an error because of a missing view file.

Comment: Use `*` instead of `*.*` for this to work with _all_ files — not only those that have a period `.` in their name

Comment: Use `set viewdir=/path/to/views` to specify where session view scripts are saved

Comment: @MarkHu `/etc/vim/vimrc` is for global/system-wide settings. You can find your user's `vimrc` file with `vim` command `:echo $MYVIMRC`. You may create either of these files if they do not exist. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977682/1054397).

Comment: I don't like this answer because it also saves the vim configuration, so you need to source the new vimrc in each file you reopen

Answer (score 9):

There is a plugin called [vim-lastplace](https://github.com/farmergreg/vim-lastplace) (I am the author) that will open your files where you left off. It improves on the above suggestions by ignoring commit messages because you're typically editing a new message and want to start at the top of the commit message file.

Comment: all you can do without plugins is best. aim for .vimrc: the smaller the code the lighter and quicker

Comment: @nilon This isn't necessarily true. There is no observable difference in speed between 1 line of code and 100 lines of code _unless_ those 100 lines of code load things that they shouldn't (in the specific case unless the plugin doesn't contain the `after` autoload directories function). After all, plugins are nothing but code, it makes no difference whether you put it in your `.vimrc` or in an external dependency.

Answer (score 7):

If you have viminfo enabled, it is as simple as `` `0 `` to go to the last edited file position. You'll notice that this is just a 'go to mark' command;

Indeed, you can later do '3 to go to the third previous edited location (perhaps in another file), and then return to the last one with `` `0 `` again

Have a look at

```
 :marks
```

to see remembered locations. Note also that viminfo stores all kinds of other stuff (like the contents of registers, marks per file, command and search history). Most people have this enabled for obvious reasons

Comment: `0 does not work for me on vim version 7.4.1689 on mac. But '0 does the trick. Is this a typo in the answer?

Comment: @alamoot no it isn't, see [vimdoc motion.txt](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark-motions) - Check what character your `\`` key actually generates, or do `:verbose map \``

Comment: you are right. According to the vimdoc both are correct!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `~/.viminfo` becomes read-only or your user don't have access to the file. That could also be a reason that vim does not store your cursor position when you close your file.

Answer (score 2):

At this point in time `:help restore-cursor` should be able to get what you want.