# How do you make Vim take you back where you were when you last edited a file?

Tags: vim, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In vim, how do I get a file to open at the same line number I closed it at last time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774560/in-vim-how-do-i-get-a-file-to-open-at-the-same-line-number-i-closed-it-at-last)

How do you make [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) take you back where you were when you last edited a file?

My work computer has this feature, but not my home computer! How do you set Vim to remember in which part of a file you were when you last edited it?

EDIT: just to be more precise, I want this behavior **when opening a new file, or on startup**.

Comment: You can set marks at various points in a file using m<letter> and return to that mark using `<same letter>, but those won't persist across, say restarts of the app or closing/opening the file (I don't think).

Comment: There is a plugin (I am the author) called [vim-lastplace](http://github.com/dietsche/vim-lastplace) that will intelligently return you to the last edit that you made.

Answer (score 13):

I have this in my .vimrc and it works:

```
" go to the position I was when last editing the file
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal g'\"" | endif
```

Comment: Only this solution worked for me, and believe me I tried most other popular solutions! Thanks.

Comment: All the plugins to do this, will all their bugs (like intermittently storing and restoring wrong cwd) replacable by this one line? Looks like that... 
Wow! I love it, many thanks!

Comment: Nope: `E576: viminfo: Missing '>' in line: au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal g'\"" | endif`

Answer (score 4):

This is done with the `viminfo` file. It should be sufficient simply to enable this feature (and ensure that the file is writable). I use:

```
set viminfo='25,\"50,n~/.viminfo
```

...which stores viminfo data into `~/.viminfo`. You can read about the other [customization options here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27viminfo%27).

Comment: I do have a viminfo file, filled with all kinds of stuff. It just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

First, check that your .vimrc file is writable.

If that isn't sufficient, add this to your .vimrc:

```
if has("autocmd")
    autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("\'") > 0 && line("\'") <= line("$") |
        \ exe "normal g`" |
    \ endif
endif
```

Comment: could you please post in "code"? Stack overflow seems to be doing weird character substitutions...

Comment: This solution won't work anyway. See my response.

Comment: How to use this? Should I press g`" or it works on file open?

Answer (score 2):

'0       // (single quote followed by zero) take you to place you last edited

Comment: If you can tell me how to execute this automatically each time a buffer is open, you get the best answer :)

Comment: put it as the last line in your .vimrc file

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty solution.

Whenever you are done editing a file and you are going to quit, just mark that place using `m<letter>`. Now you create a session file for this using `mks!`. Next time you open this file, just do ``` to reach that place.

You can have different letters to reach different places in the file. e.g. `e` for the place you were last editing or `f` function definition you were last working on etcetera. It depends upon your taste.

One thing bad about this solution is that `mks!` will create a `Session.vim` file in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

See also the Vim Wikia article on [Restore Cursor to File Position in Previous Editing Session.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session)  It looks like it lists a couple of the solutions already listed here, in addition to one larger script that specifically stores the last position for the last 10 files you've edited; you can change that value to suit your needs.