# How to open the file from last place I was in it

Tags: file, vim, save

Say I opened file X.
then I scrolled down to line number 50 then I made some modifications and closed the file.
when I re-open the file. I want Vim to save the last location in this file (line 50) and puts me in this line automatically.

This feature existed by default. I don't know the name of this feature, so I couldn't google for it.
I think I lost it because some plugins have installed later.
How I re-enable this feature again? Thanks.

Comment: this may be something that could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894330/preserve-last-editing-position-in-vim

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserve last editing position in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894330/preserve-last-editing-position-in-vim)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done by `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`, also explained under `:h restore-cursor`.

But it's not hard to add this feature yourself:

```
augroup vimStartup | au!
    autocmd BufRead * call setpos('.', getpos("'\""))
augroup end
```