# How to locate the vimrc file used by Vim?

Tags: vim, command, configuration-files

Is there a command in the Vim editor to find the `.vimrc` file location?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Just try doing the following:

```
:version
```

You will get an output which includes something like:

```
 system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
```

As noted by Herbert in comments, this is where `vim` *looks for* `vimrc`s, it doesn't mean they exist.

You can check the full path of your `vimrc` with

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
```

If the output is empty, then your `vim` doesn't use a user `vimrc` (just create it if you wish).

Comment: To clarify: `:version` tells what locations are searched, but doesn't give any info regarding what files were found.  For that the $MYVIMRC variable is useful, as is looking at output of `:scripts` for full list of all loaded script files, including all vimrc files.

Comment: @HerbertSitz `:scripts` -> `:scriptnames` (innocent typo)

Comment: I'm running vim 7.4 on OSX 10.10.5 installed with Homebrew, and `:echo $MYVIMRC` outputs nothing.

Comment: I know this is like two years old but regarding the last two comments. I got a blank output when running that command from the command line however when opening vim then typing ":echo $MYVIMRC" I got the real vimrc file.

Comment: On Arch Linux, sudo would NOT honor `/etc/vimrc` until I `ln -s`  it to `/root/.vimrc`.

Comment: I have      
user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
but 2nd user vimrc file doesn't take effect, i need to put everything i want in $HOME/.vimrc what i'm missing?

Comment: @BasharAl-Abdulhadi The `2nd user vimrc file` (e.g. `~/.vim/vimrc`) **does not take effect**, **if** the main `user vimrc file` (probably `~/.vimrc`) does exist. It's only a **strict fallback**.

Answer (score 8):

#### `:version` **does not provide a complete and exhaustive list**.

It does not list `/etc/vim` for example, despite this being the path `vim` uses to pick up `gvimrc` and `vimrc` on my Ubuntu box running vim82 from vim-gtk3.

Answer (score 6):

For `nvim` use `:scriptnames` like proposed in [Randy Morris comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155299/randy-morris)

Answer (score 6):

Run `:script`, which will show you all the locations where VIM is loading files from.
Probably, your source file is located somewhere in those directories.
If you find a different source file, you may insert the following in it:

```
if filereadable("/my/directory/.vim/.vimrc")
   source /my/directory/.vim/.vimrc
endif
```

And VIM will load your custom config file wherever it is.

Check it is working by looking for it in the output of `:script`