# Do I have to set $VIMRUNTIME if I have set $VIM?

Tags: windows, vim

I have installed gvim on Windows.

In order for gvim to find my `.vimrc` file I have set the `$VIM` (%VIM%) environment variable, pointing to the directory in which this *.vimrc* file is located.

I have not set `$VIMRUNTIME` since `:help $vimruntime` says

```
You don't normally set $VIMRUNTIME yourself, but let Vim figure it out.
```

When I start gvim, it processes my *.vimrc* file, as expected, until the line with the command `sy on`. This command tries to load the syntax files, but it can't.

I suspect the reason is this: As I have not set $VIMRUNTIME, vim automatically sets it to the value of $VIM. But under $VIM, there is no `syntax/syntax.vim` file. This syntax file is, however, under `c:\vim\vim73\syntax`.

So, If I set $VIMRUNTIME specifically to `c:\vim\vim73`, everything seems to work.

Now, why does the helpfile say I don't need to set $VIMRUNTIME if obviously I have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you place your `_vimrc`, `_gvimrc` and the directory with your custom files (`vimfiles`) within your `$HOME` directory.

Vim searches there by default.

Files located there won't be overridden when updating your Vim installation, so it's generally a good idea to do this and you won't have to mess around with any variables. If you have any custom plugins, syntax files etc, place them below `vimfiles/plugins`, `vimfiles/syntax` etc.

Furthermore, you could ask Vim where it searches for `vimrc`'s using `:version`:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
3rd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
```

as described here: [How to locate the vimrc file used by vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977649/how-to-locate-the-vimrc-file-used-by-vim-editor)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the **only** place to have *vimfiles/* and *vimrc* without messing with $VIM/$VIMRUNTIME is under $HOME?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: yep. The only safe place is in `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather set the `$HOME` environment variable to make Vim pick up your user's `.vimrc` (and potential plugins under `.vim/...`). The location of `$VIM` is supposed to represent the Vim installation base directory (including the runtime and support files).

Comment: This is certainly possible, but seems a bit of an overkill, since I need the $HOME variable in other applications too, and I don't want to mess with those applications just only because I want vim to find my .vimrc. In addition to that, I want to install some scripts and personal plugins in a non standard location so that I can have them under revision control and so that they're not overwritten when vim is re-installed.